# Where and How to set HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce, classpath

I have written a maven program and then I build it and put 3rd party jars on target/lib folder. with which command and where I can put them in my HADOOP_CLASSPATH?
The location of setting HADOOP_CLASSPATH is hadoop-env or hadoop-config?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

add your hadoop classpath in hadoop-env.sh file..there u will get a option export hadoop_classpath= ___